# Escape quotes in jquery after function, with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Kind of hard to explain, I'm using the .after() jquery function to place html in a div container, then in one of the  tags there is an onclick attribute to call a function which passes in a string (javascript variable), but this variable needs to be surrounded in quotes for the javascript function to work:

Note, the after function seems to replace single quotes with double quotes for the html attributes?

```
$("#outputsContainer tr:last").after(
    "<tr>\
       <td>"+value.name+"</td>\
       <td>"+value.status+"</td>\
       <td>\
          <a href='" + value.delete + "' onclick='" + myfunction(value.status) + "'>Delete</a>\
          <a href='" + value.download + "'>Download</a>\
       </td>\
    </tr>");
```

I've managed to get the variable value within the function, but cannot seem to place quotes around it easily

Output:

```
<a href="/item/4/download" onclick="myfunction(complete)">Download</a>
```

What I'm after (Notice the quotes around complete):

```
<a href="/item/4/download" onclick="myfunction('complete')">Download</a>
```

Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `… onclick='myfunction("+JSON.stringify(value.status)+");' …`, but seriously you should not use inline event handlers. Use the DOM instead of constructing HTML strings. I fear you have some XSS issues in that code as well.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about XSS....Noted! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping them like this `onclick=\"" + "myfunction('"+value.status+"')" +`

```
$("#outputsContainer tr:last").after(
    "<tr>\
       <td>"+value.name+"</td>\
       <td>"+value.status+"</td>\
       <td>\
          <a href='" + value.delete + "' onclick=\"" + "myfunction('"+value.status+"')" + "\">Delete</a>\
          <a href='" + value.download + "'>Download</a>\
       </td>\
    </tr>");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LT4d4/1/)

Comment: I get this returned: `onclick="myfunction(" generate_complete')'>Delete</a>`. Perhaps it's Symfony or Twig doing this..

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I've been racking my brain for ages trying to escape the quote correctly!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to concatenate a string of javascript into a string of HTML in JavaScript is just going to give you a big ball of string that is really hard to maintain.

Break the problem down. Use the DOM features that exist to help you.

```
var row = jQuery('<tr>');

var name_cell = jQuery('<td>');
name_cell.text(value.name);
row.append(name_cell);

var status_cell = jQuery('<td>');
name_cell.text(value.status);
row.append(status_cell);

var links_cell = jQuery('<td>');

var delete_link = jQuery('<a>');
delete_link.attr('href', value.delete);
delete_link.on('click', function () {
    myfunction(value.status);
});
delete_link.text('Delete');
links_cell.append(delete_link);

var download_link = jQuery('<a>');
download_link.attr('href', value.download);
download_link.text('Download');
links_cell.append(download_link);

$("#outputsContainer tr:last").after(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what @Quentin said and for doing it properly instead of building HTML string, but the code could be structured easier with jQuery's chaining and the [attributes constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

```
var row = $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>', {text: value.name}),
    $('<td>', {text: value.status}),
    $('<td>').append(
         $('<a>', {text: 'Delete', href: value.delete}).click(function () {
             myfunction(value.status);
         }),
         $('<a>', {text: 'Download', href: value.download})
    )
);
$("#outputsContainer tr:last").after(row);
```